# Is it OK to have the source of my game on Git?

Tags: git, github

By "source", I mean everything, the audio, the models, textures, the actual code and so on. I mainly want to use git so I can develop the game with my friends, and I'm using the free version of Git, but I intended for the game to be open-source anyway. Will there be a problem if the actual game content gets to a few gigabytes? Will I have to somehow exclude it from the repo and share it in another fashion at some point?

**EDIT:** I'm talking both about the actual cli software called Git, and the service called Github, which seem to go together. I plan to use `git` locally, and then push it to Github for my friends to download.

Comment: Are you talking about git, which is a piece of software that is always free, or Github, which is a website with free and paid accounts?

Comment: Here, edited. Basically, I plan to use both.

Comment: Nowadays, many different project hosting services offer git repsitories, so they don't really have to "go together".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is efficient for working with large histories, but could be inefficient in dealing with large files. Also, you'll have somewhat limited benefits from storing (large) binary files in Git. That being said, if your images, sounds, textures, ... aren't too big, you should be OK to have them managed in Git.

You might also want to separate your "assets" (images, sounds, textures, ... stuff that's not source code) into a separate git repository (included as a submodule in your source code repository), so that the later doesn't get too clunky.

Answer (score 2):

Puting all the images, textures and sounds to git repository is not a good idea because each version of a file is storred as a separate object (and not as a difference to some previous version) in repository and git is optimised to track slowly changing text (source code) files and this is what it really shines at. I you expect to have may resources I suggest, you put them in a separate archive.

Comment: But as I understood, if I don't change the textures and the models, newer versions should only have a "pointer" to the original ones. I'm pretty sure Git doesn't copy them in each version, if that's what you implied.

Comment: No, git doesn't copy them and if some image file has one version only it will occupy one object only. It is just that your repository becomes bloated with unnecessary files which doesn't need tracking of changes.

Answer (score 1):

On the [Github](https://github.com/plans) side, they say this about space:

> **Why don’t I see any disk space limits?**
>
> GitHub does not have any hard storage limits. We have soft limits for
>   each plan to prevent abuse. We find almost everyone uses a small
>   fraction of this limit. If you find yourself needing more disk space
>   for a legitimate use, please contact us.

They've been know to be pretty lenient with true open source projects running on free accounts, even back when there were explicit limits. You should probably ask before dumping gigabytes of assets into a free account though.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding large files, there are several options.  One good one is to have two repositories on GitHub; one for the large 'imagy' files and one for the rest of the source.  Make the 'imagy' repository a submodule of the source repository.  Since the 'imagy' repository should change infrequently you won't be impacted in day to day use.